# transform.SetParent(null) does not work; does not remove transform from parent

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, dotween

Using Unity 4.6 with 2D objects.
Somehow, at the end of a DOTween sequence, in the OnComplete() block, it seems that the Text label transform (recttransformLabel.DOMove) is not removed from parent. It's still in the Unity hierarchy. Btw the DOMove below does work so what this sequence does it moves a label and when the movement is done the label should be removed from hierarchy.

```
DOTween.Sequence() // http://dotween.demigiant.com/documentation.php
                    .Append(recttransformLabel.DOMove(TARGET, 0.5f * AF))
                    .OnComplete(() => {
                        Debug.Log("Remove from parent: " + recttransformLabel);
                        recttransformLabel.SetParent(null);
                    });
```

Any way to fix this? What could be the reason?

Comment: I just tried removing the OnComplete(), and removing said label somewhere else just a tad later - then it works. There is maybe something about DOTween that makes the stuff it tweens hang on to transform parents...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just setting the parent to null from the off? `recttransformlabel.parent = null`